# What is a good design pattern for tracking issues in a class?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a class that has a custom equals() method. When I compare two objects using this equals method, not only am I interested in whether or not they are equal, but if they are not equal, what was different about them. Finally, I want to be able to retrieve the differences arising from an unequal situation.

I currently use logging to display where my objects are unequal. This works, but I have a new requirement of being able to extract the actual results of the equals check for display later. I suspect there is an object-oriented design pattern for handling this type of situation.

```java
public class MyClass {
  int x;
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // make sure obj is instance of MyClass
    MyClass that = (MyClass)obj;

    if(this.x != that.x) {
      // issue that I would like to store and reference later, after I call equals
      System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
      System.out.println("that.x = " + that.x);
      return false;
    } else {
      // assume equality
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

Are there any good design pattern suggestions where some sort of work is being done, but a secondary object collects information about how well that work was done which can later be retrieved and displayed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to use the `boolean equals(Object)` API for something it was not designed for.  I don't think there is any design pattern that will allow you to do this.

Instead, you should be doing something like this:

```
public class Difference {
    private Object thisObject;
    private Object otherObject;
    String difference;
    ...
}

public interface Differenceable {
    /** Report the differences between 'this' and 'other'. ... **/
    public List<Difference> differences(Object other);
}
```

Then implement this for all classes where you want "differenceable" functionality.  For example:

```
public class MyClass implements Differenceable {
    int x;
    ...

    public List<Difference> differences(Object obj) {
        List<Difference> diffs = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!(obj instanceof MyClass)) {
             diffs.add(new Difference<>(this, obj, "types differ");
        } else {
             MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;
             if (this.x != other.x) {
                 diffs.add(new Difference<>(this, obj, "field 'x' differs");
             }
             // If fields of 'this' are themselves differenceable, you could
             // recurse and then merge the result lists into 'diffs'.
        }
        return diffs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thans, this is a nice object-oriented approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of a particular design pattern for this. One problem with this requirement is that to find out all differences between two unequal objects you would need to continue additional comparisons after the first false result (which is typically not necessary).

If I were doing this I might consider doing a normal equality test and if not equal, kick off a thread to determine why and log the results rather than incorporate such logic in the equals method itself.  This might be done in a special method outside of the equals method.